# How to read each line from a certain character to a certain character in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a text file(.txt) as this:

```
1.  getChannelI32EnumAP ("_unnamedTask<67>", "", ChanType, Analog Input, "")
Process ID: 0x00001978         Thread ID: 0x000016C4
Start Time: 16:32:37.450       Call Duration 00:00:00.000
Status: 0

2.  DAQReadNChanNSamp1DWfm ("_unnamedTask<67>", 720, 10, 0.001, {-10.4392,-10.4392,...}, 0.001, {-0.911365,-0.916462,...}, "")
Process ID: 0x00001978         Thread ID: 0x000016C4
Start Time: 16:32:37.450       Call Duration 00:00:00.719
Status: 0

3.  getChannelI32EnumAP ("_unnamedTask<67>", "", ChanType, Analog Input, "")
Process ID: 0x00001978         Thread ID: 0x000016C4
Start Time: 16:32:38.169       Call Duration 00:00:00.000
Status: 0

4.  DAQReadNChanNSamp1DWfm ("_unnamedTask<67>", 720, 10, 0.001, {-10.4392,-10.4392,...}, 0.001, {-0.931751,-0.926655,...}, "")
Process ID: 0x00001978         Thread ID: 0x000016C4
Start Time: 16:32:38.169       Call Duration 00:00:00.721
Status: 0

5.  getChannelI32EnumAP ("_unnamedTask<67>", "", ChanType, Analog Input, "")
Process ID: 0x00001978         Thread ID: 0x000016C4
Start Time: 16:32:38.890       Call Duration 00:00:00.000
Status: 0

6.  DAQReadNChanNSamp1DWfm ("_unnamedTask<67>", 720, 10, 0.001, {-10.4392,-10.4392,...}, 0.001, {-0.941944,-0.941944,...}, "")
Process ID: 0x00001978         Thread ID: 0x000016C4
Start Time: 16:32:38.890       Call Duration 00:00:00.719
Status: 0

7.  getChannelI32EnumAP ("_unnamedTask<67>", "", ChanType, Analog Input, "")
Process ID: 0x00001978         Thread ID: 0x000016C4
Start Time: 16:32:39.609       Call Duration 00:00:00.000
```

Now what i want to read is the first value from each process in each {} block,for example in process numbered 2 I want to read -10.4392 from {-10.4392,-10.4392,...} and store it to a listand from the same line I also want to read -0.911365 from {-0.911365,-0.916462,...}and store it to separate list.This Pattern is to be followed on each processs. Any idea on how to do it in python 3.

Answer (score 2):

Use a regex to split a line into `{}` blocks; split the content of each block by `,` and grab the first one.  Works in python 2 or 3.

Comment: I don't know how to do it,not read a text file before in python, can you give me a link where i can read about it.

Comment: It sounds like you need to split the problem up into each individual step. First, figure out [how to read a file](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files). Then figure out [how to read a file line by line](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects). Then figure out [how to use regex in python](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html).